# Random item drops

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing an android game where when the enemy dies it drops an item on the ground by using the down below code. The code works well for a single item, but how can I make appropriate changes to the code so that it drops a random item from an array.

```
public GameObject dropitems; 
float droprate = 0.25f;

public void DropItem()
{
    if(Random.Range(0f,1f)<=droprate)
        Instantiate (dropitems, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your `dropitems` to an array of GameObject. You can populate it as a list on the Editor screen. Also, you need to define another random number when the program flow reaches to the state in which there is an item drop. The index there should be between 0 and the number of items in `dropItems`.

```
public GameObject[] dropitems; 
float droprate = 0.25f;

public void DropItem()
{
    if(Random.Range(0f,1f)<=droprate)
    {
        int indexToDrop = Random.Range(0, dropItems.Length);
        Instantiate (dropitems[indexToDrop], this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Note that, when you use `Random.Range(int min, int max)` with the Random function, it returns an integer between min[inclusive] and max[exclusive], [as it is stated in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html).